# onCancelled() doesn't run even after cancel() is invoked and doInBackground() has finished

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having trouble with my `AsyncTask` class.
I am cancelling a task inside `doInBackground()` method and according to `AsyncTask` documentation, `onCancelled()` runs when `cancel()` is invoked and `doInBackground` has finished.

The task is successfully cancelled as I confirmed it using `isCancelled()` method, but `onCancelled()` method doesn't run after it.

from [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled(Result)),

```
protected void onCancelled ()

Applications should preferably override onCancelled(Object). 
This method is invoked by the default implementation of onCancelled(Object).

Runs on the UI thread after cancel(boolean) is invoked 
and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished.
```

This is my code for `doInbackgroud()` (not entire code is shown for simplicity) ,

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        // do Something
                    } else {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + ", before cancel");
                        cancel(true);
                        Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + ", after cancel");
                    }
     return description.toString();
   }
```

and here is `onCancelled()` method,

I have tried this,

```
protected void onCancelled(String result) {
    Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + " oncancelled");
    Toast.makeText(c, "failed to load data !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and this,

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + " oncancelled");
    Toast.makeText(c, "failed to load data !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and this,

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(String result) {
    super.onCancelled();
    Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + " oncancelled");
    Toast.makeText(c, "failed to load data !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

the `if` part of `doInbackground()` works fine and runs `onPostExecute()`, but when the `else` condition is met then `onCancelled()` method is not executed even though the task is cancelled successfully.

This is the output in `Logcat` for `else` condition.

```
false, before cancel
true, after cancel
```

It confirms that the task was cancelled.

Why `onCancelled()` method is not executed if the task is cancelled successfully. ?

Comment: Then is it still calling the onPostExecute(String) method?

Comment: No, calling nothing afterwards.

Comment: Did you override the onCancelled(String result) method?

Comment: yes..tried that too.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if you can cancel the task from within. I believe the cancel() was designed to be invoked on the task itself and not within the task (as in, not inside the doInBackground()). I could be wrong here though.

Comment: @kha You can cancel the task even from inside the doInBackground method.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Could it be because you're calling the dialog.dismiss() from a background thread? If you remove that line, does it work? I would imagine you shouldn't be able to run dismiss() on a background thread so it could in theory be raising an exception and therefore preventing the next line from being executed. Just a guess though -- Ah nvm, apparently the next lines get executed according to your logs. I have no idea what's wrong then.

Comment: Are you sure the result you expect isn't somewhere down below on the log file? You do understand it won't be between the two log lines you have shown, right?

Comment: I am more than sure, there was nothing visible in the error logs at all. Anyhow, I found the problem, the issue was, when the else block of code is executed "doInbackground" method returned a null value, It should have thrown an exception about null pointer but nothing was visible in the error logs, and this is exactly what stopping the onCancelled() method from execution. when I returned another String from inside the else block my code works perfectly.
I still don't know why no exception or error was thrown when doInBackground was returning null. Please see the answer i posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved,

the problem is,  `doInBackground()` method returns a `String`

```
return description.toString();
```

and the value of that `String` is set inside `if` block, but when `else` block is executed, the value of `description.toString()` isn't set and thus remains `null`, which caused `doinBackground` method to return a `null` value when `else` block is executed. 
I am not sure why it caused the `onCancelled()` method to not execute and not throw any error or exception.

I returned another `String` inside `else` block and it fix the problem.

```
                  else {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + ", before cancel");
                        cancel(true);
                        Log.e("Status",isCancelled() + ", after cancel");
                        return "Something";
                    }
```

Comment: Probably because the exception gets swallowed unless you catch it yourself. The implementation in `AsyncTask` looks like this: `public void run() {
                    try {
                        r.run();
                    } finally {
                        scheduleNext();
                    }
                }`. You can see where the exception disappears into the ether.